# Spam IP blacklist feed

Tags: feed, spam

Where I can get a list of IP from spam blacklist database. I need something like phishtank API where I can download their blacklist and implement it with my app.

I have seen a spam website doing lookup like http://www.mxtoolbox.com/ I was hoping I could get access to spam feed like them. csv or sql would be nice.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not use an [DNSBL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL) instead?

Comment: @sarnold - the way I understand how it works is I need to make my query to external server? Am I correct?

Comment: yes, though one or another DNSBL provider may also allow zone-transfers, letting you query a local DNS server instead, if you wish.

Comment: What's your purpose with this? Do you want to use this to block forms spam or email spam? They cone from different sources. Or do you have a different task altogether?

Comment: @triplee - It's for subdomain service. I thought if I allowed user to enter their A and MX records, I might want to check their IP and everything. I actually found one which allowed me to download a csv but I'm not sure whether it's for forum spam or email spam. - http://spam-ip.com/spam-blacklist.php

Comment: Looks like forum spam, based on a quick visit.

Comment: I still don't get it.  You want to check your client's IP addresses to make sure they're not blocked?

Comment: They're not using a feed anyway, they are doing DNSBL lookups, if you mean something like http://www.mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist%3a64.34.119.12

Comment: @triplee: I want to check whether user IP is in block list. If it is then I would disable user account. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

That site is using DNSBL lookups, not a local resource. To perform such lookups, individual blacklists sometimes differ, but in general, to look up an IP address, reverse the octets, add the DNSBL zone, and resolve; a result indicates a match (typically 127.0.0.x where the x might be a result code of some sort). So for example, to look up 123.45.67.89 in dnsbl.example.net, you'd perform an A query like this:

```
nslookup 89.67.45.123.dnsbl.example.net
```

(The program nslookup is not particularly good or convenient, but it is widely available, even on Windows.)

Read up on DNS in general and DNSBLs in particular. I have found Wikipedia to have good overviews for these topics.